# Dynamically Create and Download Doc File

Tags: php, file, http-headers, download

So I'm trying to both dynamically create a .doc file and have the user download it when he clicks a button.

These are the headers i found to download a file

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
```

And these are the headers i found to make a a word document

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename='.$myFile);
```

I'm just having a hard time just fitting the picture together because they both tasks have a 'Content-Type' header. Do i create the file first, save it, then download it? Or can i do it all (create a doc file and have user download it) in one php file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need the "headers found to make a word document." The first set are for a generic streaming download.

Comment: so i only need the last two headers to both create and have user download a doc file? does $myFile have to be an actual file on my server or is that the downloaded file name?

Comment: That will be the downloaded filename.

Comment: that makes sense...any additional headers i should include to make the download process smoother? i saw alot for downloading files.

Comment: Nope, that should be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your second set of headers are fine.  No need for the first.  The `Content-Disposition` header is the one that will *typically* force a download.  (Although, you should be aware that clients can do whatever they want with a file, and you have no direct control over this.)

You can create the file and send it straight to the client without saving it to the server's disk, depending on how you are creating this document.